# Checar a existência de um elemento usando Python & Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

estou desenvolvendo um **Web Scraping**, e estou tentando fazer um método que **quando o usuário entrar em uma determinada página que contenha um elemento com uma class expecifica o código continua**, mas enquanto isso não acontece o código continua printando "Aguardando..."

```
#Tempo de autenticar e carregar tudo

autentica_home = url.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='full-home-banners__right-banner-image nO87xn']")

while autentica_home is NULL:
    print('------------------')
    print('Aguardando usuario aceitar o código de verificação')
    sleep(1)
    print('Verificando...')
    sleep(4)
```

Porém não estou achando algum método que funcione para este caso em especifico

 O **chromedriver simplesmente crasha** quando ele não consegue localizar a div.

Ou seja, não consigo fazer ele ficar constantemente buscando pela div sem crash.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Encurtei ao máximo agora para não perder informações importantes.

Answer (score 1):

tente este comando
 `WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'coloque o XPATH que vc deseja buscar aqui')))`

70 é o máximo de tempo que ele vai aguardar se quiser esperar por mais tempo aumente

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ##### **<sub>O texto a seguir é uma tradução parcial do Capitulo 5 da [documentação Selenium Webdriver Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).</sub>**

## 5. Esperas.

Atualmente, a maioria dos aplicativos da Web está usando técnicas *AJAX*. Quando uma página é carregada pelo navegador, os elementos dessa página podem ser carregados em intervalos de tempo diferentes. Isso dificulta a localização de elementos: se um elemento ainda não estiver presente no *DOM*, uma função de localização gerará uma exceção [`ElementNotVisibleException`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/common/exceptions.html#ElementNotVisibleException).
Usando esperas, podemos resolver esse problema. A espera fornece alguma folga entre as ações executadas - principalmente localizar um elemento ou qualquer outra operação com o elemento.

O *Selenium Webdriver* fornece dois tipos de espera - implícita e explícita:

- Uma espera explícita faz com que o *WebDriver* espere que uma determinada condição ocorra antes de prosseguir com a execução.
- Uma espera implícita faz o *WebDriver* pesquisar o *DOM* por um determinado período de tempo ao tentar localizar um elemento.

## 5.1. Esperas Explícitas.

Uma espera explícita é um código que você define para aguardar uma determinada condição ocorrer antes de prosseguir no código. O caso extremo disso é [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), que define a condição para um período de tempo exato de espera.
Existem alguns métodos de conveniência fornecidos que ajudam você a escrever um código que aguardará apenas o tempo necessário. *WebDriverWait* em combinação com *ExpectedCondition* é uma maneira de fazer isso.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://algum_domínio/url_que_demora_carregar")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "meuElementoDinâmico"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

No código acima, o *Selenium* aguardará no máximo 10 segundos para que um elemento que corresponda aos critérios fornecidos seja encontrado. Se nenhum elemento for encontrado nesse tempo, um [`TimeoutException`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/common/exceptions.html#TimeoutException) será lançado.
Por padrão, `WebDriverWait` chama `ExpectedCondition` a cada 500 milissegundos até retornar com sucesso. `ExpectedCondition` retornará `True` em caso de sucesso ou `None` se não localizar um elemento.

### Condições de espera.

Existem algumas condições comuns que são frequentemente usadas ao automatizar navegadores da web. Abaixo estão listados os nomes de cada um.
A distribuição *Selenium Python* fornece alguns [métodos convenientes](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) para que você não precise codificar uma classe `expect_condition` ou criar seu próprio pacote de utilitários para eles.

- title_is
- title_contains
- presença_do_elemento_localizado
- visibilidade_do_elemento_localizado
- visibilidade_de
- presença_de_todos_elementos_localizado
- text_to_be_present_in_element
- text_to_be_present_in_element_value
- frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
- invisibilidade_do_elemento_localizado
- element_to_be_clickable
- staleness_of
- element_to_be_selected
- element_location_to_be_selected
- element_selection_state_to_be
- element_location_selection_state_to_be
- alert_is_present

---

Aplicando no seu exemplo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://algum_domínio/url_que_demora_carregar")
try:
    print('------------------')
    print('Aguardando usuário aceitar o código de verificação....')
    try:
      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
          EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='full-home-banners__right-banner-image nO87xn']"))
      )
      print('Processando a entrada do usuário...')
      ...
    except TimeoutException:
      print('Usuário demorou muito para responder.')
      raise
    ... 
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

assim funciona:

def ElementoExiste(navegador, elemento):
try:
retorno= navegador.find_element(By.XPATH,elemento)
print(retorno)
if retorno!='':
return True
except NoSuchElementException:
print('Item tela não encontrado(Função elementoexiste())')
return False

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).